# Can i use an "a" element directly in <ul> or <ol>?

Tags: list, html-lists

As the topic. I know I can use it and it works but is it good way to make my markup and css shorter? Can I use this?:

```
nav > ul > a
```

instead of this :

```
nav > ul > li > a
```

Answer (score 0):

Look at the specification:

[For UL](https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/grouping-content.html#the-ul-element):

> Content model: Zero or more li and script-supporting (script, template) elements.

[For OL](https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/grouping-content.html#the-ol-element)

> Content model: Zero or more li and script-supporting (script, template) elements.

So: **No**.